# Secure Register - Login Portal

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-policy, salt, registration

Im trying to create a secure portal for parents to view their sons or daughters information.

I would need to have a register page. Im having trouble with hashing and salting the password.

Then I need help with decoding the hashed and salt password for them to login in.

Comment: I'm afraid you cant decode hashes. What you simply do is when they enter their credentials to login you hash and salt it and compare the hash with the hash in the database in order to login.

Comment: This looks like a programming question rather than an information security question.  You're going to need to add a lot more detail before it is a good fit for StackOverflow, however.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't decode the salt/hash pair, you would instead run the salt/hash process again every time they enter their password on your site and compare the output to the stored salt/hash pair you have.

This is to avoid ever storing plain text passwords and if you're ever breached, it makes it exponentially harder to gain usable passwords from the information stolen.

The process you choose to salt/hash is up to you. There are a lot of functions ready to do this for you, depending on the language chosen.